# Devise don't return login errors but works with everything else (forgot password, create account)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, rubygems

I have literally the same code for forgot password and login but the login gives me no errors after submitting the form with wrong data or empty.

```html
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |form| %>
        <%= render "devise/shared/error_messages", resource: resource %>
        <div class="space-y-4">
          <div class="space-y-1">
            <%= form.label :email, 'Email', class: "input-label" %>
            <%= form.text_field :email, placeholder: 'Enter your email address...', autofocus: true, autocomplete: "email", class: "text-field input-lg w-full" %>
            <% unless resource.errors[:email].empty? %>
              <div class="flex space-x-1">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-4 w-4 text-error" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor">
                  <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M18 10a8 8 0 11-16 0 8 8 0 0116 0zm-7 4a1 1 0 11-2 0 1 1 0 012 0zm-1-9a1 1 0 00-1 1v4a1 1 0 102 0V6a1 1 0 00-1-1z" clip-rule="evenodd"/>
                </svg>
                <span class="txt_caption text-error ">The Email field <%= resource.errors[:email].first %></span>
              </div>
            <% end %>
          </div>

          <%= render partial: "input", locals: { form: form,
                                                 type: :password,
                                                 label: 'Password',
                                                 field: :password,
                                                 placeholder: 'Enter you password...'
          } %>

          <%= form.submit "Log In Account", class: "btn-primary btn-lg w-full" %>
      <% end %>
```

The only difference is the path, I have the default devise session controller.
This is my session controller :

```html
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    user_root_url(business_id: resource.business.id)
  end
end
```

Email was at a partial it was working just fine.
When I submit the google console gives me this:
"POST http://localhost:3000/accounts/login 401 (Unauthorized)"
and the logs

```
Started POST "/accounts/login" for ::1 at 2021-12-22 16:26:36 +0000
Processing by SessionsController#create as TURBO_STREAM
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "user"=>{"email"=>"", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Log In Account"}
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 348)
```